# loop inside the foreach

Tags: loop, query

In my index page, I want to display 12 posts for each category, so I iterate the categories:

```
<?php foreach ($sub_cates as $cate) { ?>

    <section class="b">
                <div class="grid">
                    <header class="title">
                        <h2><?php echo $cate->name ?><a class="more" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cate) ?>">More</a></h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php
                        //rewind_posts();
                        query_posts(array(
                            "category" => $cate->term_id,
                            "numberposts" => 12
                        ));
                        $w = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
                        while (have_posts()) {
                            the_post();
                            ?>
                            <article class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
                                <?php get_template_part("grid-item") ?>
                            </article>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

However each section print the same collections of posts, even after I use the `rewind_posts` before the loop.

What's going on?

Comment: is your category name dispaly correctly?

Comment: Yes, the category name is right, so are the categories links.

Comment: have you tried resetting the query " wp_reset_query(); " ?

Comment: `wp_reset_query` does not work.

Comment: have you tried echoing " $cate->term_id " ? does it display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figure it out.

It seems that the `get_posts` and `query_posts` accept different arguments, when I use the `get_posts` I can setup the arguments like this:

```
                    get_posts(array(
                        "category" => $cate->term_id,
                        "numberposts" => 12
                    ));
```

While when I use `query_posts` I have change that to:

```
                    query_posts(array(
                        "cat" => $cate->term_id,
                        "numberposts" => 12
                    ));
```

Notice the `category` to `cat`. This is a sad story.:(

Answer (score 0):

The job of [`rewind_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) is to rewind the same query -- which is not was you want in this case.

Have you tried with [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_1) instead? [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) is needed for the `$post` object but [`wp_reset_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) isn't required after the loop in this case.

```
<?php foreach ( $sub_cates as $cate ) { ?>

    <section class="b">
        <div class="grid">
            <header class="title">
                <h2><?php echo $cate->name ?><a class="more" href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cate ) ?>">More</a>
                </h2>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <?php

                $posts = get_posts( array (
                    "category"    => $cate->term_id, // empty value will query a bunch of posts
                    "numberposts" => 12,
                ) );

                foreach ( $posts as $post_object ) {

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                    ?>
                    <article class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
                        <?php get_template_part( "grid-item" ) ?>
                    </article>
                    <?php
                }

                wp_reset_postdata(); // like wp_reset_query() but for $post

                ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The manner you mentioned in your answer is what I used before, it worked. I just tried to change to the standard loop where I meet this problem.

Comment: You should limit by post type and check if `$cate->term_id` exists. If you run that category query with an empty value it'll get anything it can.